# connecting all points between two subplots in matlab?

Tags: matlab, lines, subplot

I want to connect all the points in a scatterplot in one subplot to another subplot. Both the scatterplots have been linked. So points in same row between subplots to be joined by lines. How to join multiple lines between subplots?

Comment: Are you trying to draw lines from one set of axes to another?

Comment: @Doresoom yes from x,y coordinate in subplot 1 to x1,y1 coordinate in subplot 2

Comment: @David_G i tried the given code, it didn't help me. Instead it is giving me a single plot

Answer (score 0):

Well, the matlab command `line` draws the line in the current axes, so it is not useful for connecting points between two subplots. However, there is another command `annotation` which draws on the figure. You might use it, but in this case you will have to transfomr the coordinates of your points to the coordinates on the figure, which might be a good deal of work.

Here is example how annotation lines work:

```
annotation(gcf,'line',[1 0.553571428571429],...
    [0.1 0.891895015906681]);
```